# Check if lisp object ends in NIL

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to write an fx in lisp to tell if an object ends in nil.

```
(setq isList (lambda (listOfValues)
    (if (null listOfValues) t)
    ( funcall isList (cdr listOfValues) )
  )
)
```

However, I am having trouble checking if its nil in all cases. In particular, cdr would fail at last elt if it is not a list. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Before we get closer to answer your actual question, a few things. First, use `defun` to define functions, not "set a variable to a lambda", it will make you happier down the line. Second, Common Lisp style would vale been one of `values`, `list-of-values`, or just `list` (that would indicate we knew it was a list, so I would probably just have gone with `values` here), not "listOfValues" (case is typically smashed, and neither "listofvalues" nor "LISTOFVALUES" are easy to read).

So, back to the code. A list is composed of cons cells, of either atoms or other cons cells. We have two test functions, either `consp` or `atom` that would be useful in this case. We know that if we're looking at a cons, we need to recurse on its cdr, otherwise we're at the last element and can just check if we're looking at nil.

```
(defun is-proper-list (values)
  (if (consp values)
      (is-proper-list (cdr values))
      (null values))) ;; We could do this test as (eql nil) as well
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done faster with

```
(defun listp (l)
  (tailp nil l))
```

`(tailp nil ...)` tests, whether `nil` is the end of a given object after `cdr`-ing to the end.
`tailp` is a very special function. So don't use it without understanding it.

`(tailp '(b c) '(a b c))` is e.g. NOT `T`, because `'(b c)` is not the same object like the `( ... b c)`. But in this case, because `NIL` is `'()` and is unique in Lisp, any `nil` is object-identical. Therefore one can use `tailp` here for this specific test, whether a given list ends with `NIL`.

`listp` is a lisp-convention conform name for this.
(predicate functions returning booleans ending with `p` for predicate.
Since no `-` used in the name, attach `p` without `-` otherwise attach `-p`).

```
(tailp (cdr '(a b c)) '(a b c)) ;; NIL
;; because the two lists are not object-identical

(setq l '(a b c))
(tailp (cddr l) l) ;; T ;; object-identical
```